# Python, updating variables manual while code running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that contains a variable that I want to change manually when I want without stopping the main loop neither pause it (with input()). I can't find a library that allows me to set manually in the run, or access the RAM memory to change that value.
for now I set a file watcher that reads the parameters every 1 minutes but this is inefficient way I presume.

Comment: That is a strange usecase. could you tell us more about ? Because I have been coding for 10 years, and never need something like that, so maybe a different code approach may save you fom that

Comment: Basically I coded a heavy simulation, I took all the CPUs  in all the central calculation machins without telling other researchers in the lab. I am watching their activities and once I notice anyone logging in on one of the stations I want to minimize my task load by changing the number of CPUs parallelisation, this way I avoid them getting to my office complaining.

Comment: I don't need to show you a code I think it's clear I have a variable in a closed loop I want to change it manually without breaking or pausing the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want to expose API. You did it with files which works but less common. You can use common best practices such as:

1. HTTP web-server. You can do it quickly with [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/)/[bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).
2. [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)
3. pub/sub mechanism - Redis, Kafka (more complicated, requires another storage solution - the DB itself).

I guess that there are tons of other solution but you got the idea. I hope that's what you're looking for.

With those solution you can manually trigger your endpoint and change whatever you want in your application.

Comment: Following down the rabbit hole of the ideas you mentioned I found a great generalized term which is IPC Inter-process communication. I followed the link to find some great ideas for sit-and-watch type of side code while a loop is rolling. The link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Comment: Great, good luck!